# How do i add a pic with hyperlink and align them to center as in my wireframe?

Tags: html, css

This is my wireframe:

[image: this is my wireframe]
So I'm actually creating a webpage for my mini project, I have included the wireframe above, I actually needs to put two pics with links and aliggned centered on my page with the footer and sidenav back button, so I have succesfully created the footer and sidenav, but I need to put my two pics and with hyperlink and align them to center as in the wireframe. Please refer to the wireframe.

here is my codes the css and html

```css
/*the sidebar back button*/

/* Style the links inside the sidenav */

#mySidenav a {
  position: absolute;
  /* Position them relative to the browser window */
  left: -80px;
  /* Position them outside of the screen */
  transition: 0.3s;
  /* Adds transition on hover */
  padding: 15px;
  /* 15px padding */
  width: 100px;
  /* Sets a specific width */
  text-decoration: none;
  /* Remove underline */
  font-size: 20px;
  /* Increase font size */
  color: white;
  /* White text color */
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  /* Rounded corners on the top right and bottom right side */
}

#mySidenav a:hover {
  left: 0;
  /* On mouse-over, make the elements appear as they should */
}


/* The about link: 20px from the top with a green background */

#about {
  top: 20px;
  background-color: #42beb8;
}


/*The Footer*/

#footer {
  background-color: rgba(59, 195, 154, 0.87);
  width: 100%;
  height: 95px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 20%;
}


/* footer div links settings*/

.footer a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(230, 182, 64);
  color: black;
}

#footer div {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
}

/* footer links margins settings */

#footer div h5,
h2 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* horizontal line below footer div */

hr {
  width: 85%;
  margin-left: 8%;
  margin-right: 20%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 1;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>products</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="products.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!--sidenav-->
  <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <a href="#" id="about">Back</a>
  </div>

  <!--The footer section-->
  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="footer">
        <br>
        <div align="left">
          <h5><a href="social.html">Social Media</a></h5>
        </div>
        <div align="left">
          <h5><a href="mainpage.html">Home</a></h5>
        </div>
        <div align="center">
          <h2> <a href="mainpage.html">Buystuff</a>
            <h2>
        </div>
        <div align="right">
          <h5><a href="games.html">Games</a></h5>
        </div>
        <div align="right">
          <h5> <a href="products.html">Products</a></h5>
        </div>
        <hr>
      </div>

    </div>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use flexbox

```css
/*the sidebar back button*/
/* Style the links inside the sidenav */
#mySidenav a {
  position: absolute; /* Position them relative to the browser window */
  left: -80px; /* Position them outside of the screen */
  transition: 0.3s; /* Adds transition on hover */
  padding: 15px; /* 15px padding */
  width: 100px; /* Sets a specific width */
  text-decoration: none; /* Remove underline */
  font-size: 20px; /* Increase font size */
  color: white; /* White text color */
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0; /* Rounded corners on the top right and bottom right side */
}

#mySidenav a:hover {
  left: 0; /* On mouse-over, make the elements appear as they should */
}

/* The about link: 20px from the top with a green background */
#about {
  top: 20px;
  background-color: #42beb8;
  color:red;
}

#container{
margin-top:80px;
display:flex;
justify-content:space-evenly;
align-items:center;
}


















/*The Footer*/
#footer {
    background-color: rgba(59, 195, 154, 0.87);
    width: 100%;
    height: 95px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 20%;
    
    }
  
    /* footer div links settings*/
    .footer a:hover {
      background-color: rgb(230, 182, 64);
      color: black;
      
    }
  
  
    #footer div{
      display: block;
      float: right;
      width: 20%;
      
     
    }
  
  
  /* footer links margins settings */
    #footer div h5, h2 {
      margin-bottom: 0;
      margin-top: 0;
      text-decoration: none;
      
    }
  
  /* horizontal line below footer div */
  hr {width: 85%;margin-left: 8%;margin-right: 20%;height: 1px;background-color:black; opacity: 1;margin-top: 3%;margin-bottom: auto;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>products</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="products.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <!--sidenav-->
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
      <a href="#" id="about">Back</a>
    </div>


<div id='container'>

<div id='left'>
<a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x250.jpg?" ></a>
</div>

<div id='right'>
<a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x250.jpg?" ></a>
</div>

</div>







        <!--The footer section-->

    <footer class="footer">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="footer">
        <br>
        <div align="left"><h5><a href="social.html">Social Media</a></h5></div>
        <div align="left"><h5><a href="mainpage.html">Home</a></h5></div>
        <div align="center"><h2> <a href="mainpage.html">Buystuff</a><h2></div>
        <div align="right"><h5><a href="games.html">Games</a></h5></div>
        <div align="right"><h5> <a href="products.html">Products</a></h5></div>
        <hr>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </footer>
   

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following is what you are trying to achieve.

```css
/*the sidebar back button*/


/* Style the links inside the sidenav */

#mySidenav a {
  position: absolute;
  /* Position them relative to the browser window */
  left: -80px;
  /* Position them outside of the screen */
  transition: 0.3s;
  /* Adds transition on hover */
  padding: 15px;
  /* 15px padding */
  width: 100px;
  /* Sets a specific width */
  text-decoration: none;
  /* Remove underline */
  font-size: 20px;
  /* Increase font size */
  color: white;
  /* White text color */
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  /* Rounded corners on the top right and bottom right side */
}

#mySidenav a:hover {
  left: 0;
  /* On mouse-over, make the elements appear as they should */
}


/* The about link: 20px from the top with a green background */

#about {
  top: 20px;
  background-color: #42beb8;
}


/*The Footer*/

#footer {
  background-color: rgba(59, 195, 154, 0.87);
  width: 100%;
  height: 95px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 20%;
}


/* footer div links settings*/

.footer a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(230, 182, 64);
  color: black;
}

#footer div {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
}


/* footer links margins settings */

#footer div h5,
h2 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* horizontal line below footer div */

hr {
  width: 85%;
  margin-left: 8%;
  margin-right: 20%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 1;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}


/* Main Section */

.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.pic-container {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 45%;
  height: 80%;
}

.pic {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/3841338/pexels-photo-3841338.jpeg");
}
```

```html
<!--sidenav-->
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="#" id="about">Back</a>
</div>

<!--Main Section-->


<div class="main">
  <div class="pic-container">
    <div class="pic pic1">
    </div>
    <p class="description">This is a description</p>
  </div>

  <div class="pic-container">

    <div class="pic pic2">
    </div>
    <p class="description">This is a description</p>
  </div>

</div>




<!--The footer section-->

<footer class="footer">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="footer">
      <br>
      <div align="left">
        <h5><a href="social.html">Social Media</a></h5>
      </div>
      <div align="left">
        <h5><a href="mainpage.html">Home</a></h5>
      </div>
      <div align="center">
        <h2> <a href="mainpage.html">Buystuff</a>
          <h2>
      </div>
      <div align="right">
        <h5><a href="games.html">Games</a></h5>
      </div>
      <div align="right">
        <h5> <a href="products.html">Products</a></h5>
      </div>
      <hr>
    </div>

  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: thanks for helping me,i really appreciate it but this was not what i was looking for,but thanks anyway